# How to reduce code from different alert-dialogue?

Tags: java, android

I have three types alert dialogue. Each alert dialogue behave differently but I don't like to write three types of alert dialogue in same class because it extends the class size drastically. Here are the three alert dialogue given below:

```
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
        final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity)
            .setTitle("Alert !")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            result.confirm();
                        }
                    }).setCancelable(false).create().show();

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message,
        final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(currentActivity)
            .setTitle("Confirmation")
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            result.confirm();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                    new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            result.cancel();
                        }
                    }).setCancelable(false).create().show();

    return true;
}
```

And the last alert dialogue is:

```
public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(final String origin,
        final GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {

    final boolean remember = true;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            WebviewActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Locations");
    builder.setMessage(" Would like to use your Current Location")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Allow",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            callback.invoke(origin, true, remember);

                            SharedPreferences pref = currentActivity
                                    .getPreferences(currentActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref
                                    .edit();
                            editor.putBoolean("isLocationAvailable",
                                    true);
                            editor.commit();

                            webview.loadUrl(getUrl(gps.getLatitude(),
                                    gps.getLongitude(), "true"));
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Don't Allow",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            callback.invoke(origin, false, remember);
                            webview.loadUrl(getUrl("", "", "false"));

                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

How can I reduce the code size. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

I also like to keep classes short, but I don't think it should influence your design.  You can put the alert building code in another class file if you really want to.

I would not try to coerce the geolocation alert with onJsAlert/onJsConfirm since it is quite different.  But you could do something if you really wanted to reuse some code for those two (onJsAlert/onJsConfirm).  The positive OnClickListener could be defined outside and shared for onJsAlert/onJsConfirm.  You could instead write a common method for building those two alert dialogs, with an if-statement that checks if a negative button should be added or not.